# The underlying provider failed on Open: Sequence contains more than one matching element

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After weeks of working fine with no changes, today this line:

```
return db.Set<TEntity>().Find(primaryKeys);
```

suddenly throws:

```
The underlying provider failed on Open: Sequence contains more than one matching element
```

The code continues to work fine in another project using the same database instance.

Many other questions on this error were resolved by updating EntityFramework Packages. I am using .NET Framework 4.8 and these packages:

- EntityFramework: 6.4.4
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core: 2.2.4
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework: 2.2.4
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin: 2.2.4

Appear to be the latest.

I am approaching the point of needing to reinstall Visual Studio or even Windows but really don't want to do that.

Comment: I mean that particular exception is for when the Database contains more than one element you claim is supposed to be unique somewhere. 

So you are trying to access a table, that has multiple instances of results, based on a filter set that is supposed to be able to provide only 1 result.

Reinstalling windows or visual studio or whatever, won't solve this

Answer (score 0):

Turning on database logging with: db.Database.Log = Console.Write;

Output: iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Which revealed the problem was actually my project being unable to access the database and had nothing to do with matching elements